# Can we replace 'e' with 'o' and 'o' with 'e' in "Hello World" with replace function to get output "Holle Werld" in Python?

Tags: python, string, replace, translate

I tried this with replace function but of no use.

```
s = "Hello World"
s = s.replace("e","o").replace("o","e")
print(s)
#output= Helle Werld
```

Then I tried this with translate function

```
s = "hello world"
dictionary = {'e':'o', 'o': 'e'}
transTable = s.maketrans(dictionary) 
s = s.translate(transTable)
print(s)
#output= Holle Werld
```

Can we simplify this?

Comment: I think the latter should be the simplest way.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen You forget `ord`.

Comment: `s.translate(s.maketrans(dict(zip("oe", "eo"))))` do you call that simplified ?

Comment: minor simplification: `s.maketrans("eo", "oe")`.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "hello world"
t = s.maketrans("eo", "oe") 
print(s.translate(t))
```

output = holle werld

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest Translate method till now.(Thanks @hiro-protagonist)

```
s = "hello world"
print(s.translate(s.maketrans("eo", "oe")))
```

Or
you can also try this instead using Replace method

```
s = "hello world"
s=s.replace("e","\e").replace("o","\o").replace("\e","o").replace("\o","e")
print(s)
```